# CSS Styling Navigation Buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to replicate the Navigation Buttons which exist within the ASP.NET Site:
http://forums.asp.net/user/editprofile.aspx#   (you have to log-in to see the tabs)

[image]

As you can see for an onClick Event the background of the Tab changes to white and the Text changes from Blue to Black.  There is also a top left and right border applied to the Tab for an onClick. Also on the Hover the underline for the Button's Hyperlink appears.

I tried to replicate as much as I could with Firebug, but Im missing some things.  For example in my Fiddle the Button's Hyperlink remains underlined.

Im also very unclear about the Click Event within the JQuery and how this is changing the background color from blue to white, and how the border is applied.
if anyone could improve upon this I would really appreciate it.

Here is what I have so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/XrQys/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to the page but if you look at the CSS it should be pretty straight forward to see what they are doing. A great way to do this is to use Chrome and then when you right click on an item you can say "Inspect Element" and it will show you the CSS classes that are applied to the element/link.

To remove the underline on a hyperlink look at CSS's [text-decoration](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_text-decoration.asp).

Usually to change the color of a button with jQuery, the easiest way is to use the .click() method and then to add a [class](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to the object.

```
$('a#my_link').click(function(){
  $(a#my_link.active).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  ... do other stuff
}
```

**untested**

http://jsfiddle.net/CrvJN/8/

Notes about what I did:

- removed the background-color for `.common-heading-tabs a` this way the blue and white class could actually have an effect
- add/removed the blue/white class based on the click
- returned false in order to make sure the anchor tag didn't perform an unwanted action
- white == active in this case
- added class="blue" to each anchor

There are some other improvements you could do on `.common-heading-tabs a` and `.common-heading-tabs`, but that's outside the scope of this question. I would suggest going through W3School's lessons on CSS to get a better idea of what is  available so you aren't having to copy and paste so much compiled CSS from sites. IMHO. :)

Comment: Yea, just played around with it (forked yours). First time messing around with that site, pretty cool. Hope that helps.

Comment: When you forked it, you actually saved it as your own Fiddle.  Could you send me the link so I can see what you changed?

Comment: I added it to the bottom of my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from scratch, but it's already done for you...and done WELL.

Check out [Jquery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

They're cross-browser tested, and extremely flexible.  One line of code, and done.  Full API for interactions.  And, to get the look you desire, you can control everything from the hover effect to background, to borders in ThemeRoller, easily re-styling the base scheme to perfectly match your own.

Let the power of many people solve this problem and you can apply your effort to something more important...or better yet to help the programming community.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to style the anchors so that they don't show the underline:

```
ul li a:visited, ul li a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* I might as well show the blue and white classes */
.blueClass {
  background: blue; /*this should be the specific shade of blue you want */
}
.whiteClass {
  background: white;
}
```

Give all the tabs the class .blueClass, except for the default tab, which should have the .whiteClass

As for the javascript, you need to use the .click() function in JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnSiteOptions').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Toggles the classes blueClass and whiteClass.  You'll need to make these.
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('blueClass whiteClass');
    });
});
```

Note: I didn't look closely at how the website you provided implemented this feature. I did, however, demonstrate how it's usually done.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how jsfiddle works with javascript.  I saw that it had Jquery, and that it has the onLoad function, so it should work if you remove the "$(function() {" and the last "});".  I haven't really messed with jsfiddle before.

Answer (score 0):

it's really almost there just a few odd bits like containing the floated li's and adding some borders on the default tabs, the same color as their background, so they don't "jump" when hovered or clicked. The borders are always there, the colors just change.

Then I see you already have a `selected` class built in so I just used that and made it match the `:hover` styles with the jQuery function adding or removing that class as necessary.

#### Example fiddle : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/xQq7d/)

Comment: thanks for your response, I was able to get most of the functionality working.  However Im still having problems with the Borders.  I posted a new Thread about this, if you care to take a look:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083513/css-tabs-border-issue

Comment: @Paul you're welcome.. I didn't understand as incorporated the border toggle into my fiddle, but fiddle got lost! - I've now replaced it with new one in answer.. pls take another look see if that includes the answer, thanks