# CSS Tabs Border Issue

Tags: css

Im having a problem to determine how to manipulate the Borders for some Tabs

[image]

You can see the functionality here on ASP.NET if you are logged-in http://forums.asp.net/user/editprofile.aspx#

You can see for an onClick Event the background-color of the Tab changes to white like its supposed to.

The problem that Im having has to do with the Borders for onClick:

The border-bottom should change from the grey color to white.
The border-left and the border-right should change to the grey color.

Likewise when a Tab is not selected:
The border-bottom should change to the grey color from white.
The border-left and border-right should not have a border.

In my CSS, Im using both the blue and white class for the JavaScript.  However I also have: .common-heading-tabs a.selected   and this is confusing me.

Here is my Fiddle- if someone could help It would be great
http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/ZSeFA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just modified the CSS class for `.white` a little bit, your CSS mark-up was not the standard:

```
border-left-color: #A0AFC3;
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
```

Additionally, to get the bottom border to go away, you have one of two options, you could do one of either

- remove the bottom border from the `.common-heading-tabs a` class and add it to the `.blue` class
- add `border-bottom-color:white !important;` to the `.white` class

The reason that you were seeing the behavior that you were was because the standard tab had a border (from `.common-heading-tabs a`), and when you switched to white, you tried to change the color or some of the borders, but you used `border-left-color-value` rather than simply `border-left-color`, and then you didn't modify the border on the bottom on the tab for the white class, hence either moving the bottom border declaration out of `.common-heading-tabs a` or explicitly coloring the `bottom-border-color:white !important`

Hope that helps!

**Edit**:

You requested having a border run between the tabs, if you were to modify the class `.left-col` and add to it:

```
.left-col
{
 border-bottom-color: black;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

That should do the trick, maybe you should get rid of the borders on the other tabs, if this is what you're looking for, because the double border looks funky.

Let me know if I can help any more

Comment: @Brett I knew that the CSS was very different, and I got it from the example site.  With your help and Sirvivir, I was able to get this to function:  http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/ZSeFA/   If you run this do you see a piece that Im missing at the bottom?  Between the Tab Buttons?

Comment: @Paul - what I would do is add some code to the div with class `left-col`, I'll put it in my answer

Comment: @Brett wouldnt I still need to modify the bottom-border?  As you can see it spans across all of the tabs, except for that Tab that is selected.

Comment: @Paul - isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Brett I believe that did the trick. I removed the bottom-border from the Blue Class and now its just in the left-col class as you suggested.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Brett the 1 thing that I did notice is that once a Tab is clicked the other Blue Tabs that arent activated have a space between the Tab and the bottom-border http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/ZSeFA/

Comment: @Paul - that's because the `border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF !important;` that we put in `.white` earlier. Remove that, and your space will be gone. Basically, the one tab got 1px higher than the rest, so you saw a gap. That work?

Comment: @Brett I still have a slight issue with the bottom-border for the #mid-featureleft-client .SerialScrollTabs Class.  Are you free to take a look?          It seems when the Page first loads, the bottom-border for that Class I just mentioned, doesnt appear.  This only appears until a Button is clicked.  I think part of the reason is that this class bottom margin is -1:  .navigations li{margin:0 5px -1px 0;} http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/nJu5D/

Comment: @Paul-What I could see was that you weren't assigning the `white` class to any of the tabs on the page load, so even though tab1 was being displayed, it didn't have css class `white` therefore doesn't have any borders. if that isn't the problem you're talking about, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For an example to make bottom border white look this

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p 
{
border-style:solid;
border-bottom-color:white;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Thomas I have that as you can see in my Fiddle:                    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;

Answer (score 0):

You have some inheritance going on. Adding explicit values to the `.blue` class and `important` to the one in `.white` worked.

```
.blue {   
    background-color: #D7DFEA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
.white {   
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #A0AFC3;
    border-left: 1px solid #A0AFC3;
    border-right: 1px solid #A0AFC3;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: do you think it would be safe to then remove .common-heading-tabs a.selected

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as far as I can see, is that while both `.common-heading-tabs a` and `.white` are applied to the link, the former is the "more specific" CSS class, which means the browser gives it precedence while determining which styles to apply.

If you want to make sure the `.white` style overrides the border, you can either add `!important` to the border style:

```
.white {   
    background-color: white !important;
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF !important;
    border-bottom-style: solid !important;
    border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
    ...
}
```

or redesign the appliance of your classes in such a way that conflicting border styles aren't applied to begin with, which in your case could for example mean moving the blue border style from `.common-heading-tabs a` to `.blue`.